# ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, mongomapper, devise

```
gem 'rails', '3.0.0'
gem 'devise'
gem 'bson_ext', '>= 1.0.7'
gem 'bson', '>= 1.0.7'
gem 'mongo_mapper', :branch => 'rails3', :git => 'http://github.com/jnunemaker/mongomapper.git'
gem 'devise-mongo_mapper', :git => 'git://github.com/collectiveidea/devise-mongo_mapper'
```

With the above setup I get the following errors on requests:

```
Started GET "/users/sign_out" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-09-27 13:16:30 +0300
  Processing by Devise::SessionsController#destroy as HTML
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 19ms
[2010-09-27 13:16:31] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
    /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `eof?'
    /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `run'
    /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'


Started GET "/users/edit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2010-09-27 13:16:35 +0300
  Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#edit as HTML
Completed   in 16ms
[2010-09-27 13:16:35] ERROR Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
    /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `eof?'
    /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:56:in `run'
    /usr/local/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

The user model:

```
class User
  include MongoMapper::Document
  plugin MongoMapper::Devise
  devise :registerable, :database_authenticatable, :recoverable
end
```

Ideas?

Comment: What's in the view? Is it the standard devise view or have you customized it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My quick guess is this looks like you have a problem with your sessions and protect_from_forgery is kicking in.

I had a similar problem and smashed my head against the wall for a few days, it turned out to be I was assigning an entire object to a session object instead of just the id. A quick note, non-GET requests are the ones that trigger the protect_from_forgery.

Comment: I just migrated an application from OpenShift 2 to OpenShift 3 and now I'm getting this. I suspect the issue may be what you describe, but my `session[:...]` assignments look fine. Could it be anything else that I may `grep` for?

Answer (score 15):

WebRick has been replaced with Thin.

Doing the following worked for me:

**Gemfile:**

```
gem 'thin'
```

Now do `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Adding this to my ***development.rb*** file fixed the issue.

```
 config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true
  config.web_console.whitelisted_ips = replace_this_with_the_public_ip
```

Comment: I still get this issue whenever I try to load redmine from the browser. I am not sure what is missing. I usded thin, there is no error, but the page is not loading.

Comment: In my case the problem was a corrupted svg image that could not be loaded. Replacing the file fixed the issue.